# German PR through spouse

Tags: germany, working-visas, eu, blue-card, marriage

I have been living in Germany for around 3.5 years. I came here as a student but I’ve been doing a full time tech based job (with a Blue card) for almost 1 year now.

My husband (since Dec 2021) has also been living in Germany for around 5 years. He came as a student and now has been working on a Blue card for almost 2.6 years. We’ve been married for 7 months now.

He will apply for a Permanent Residency once his 33 months of Blue card complete (after 1 month).

If my husband gets a PR, can I also get one through him?

I read that if the spouse (me) has been living in Germany for 3 years, the spouse can also apply for a PR. But since we have only been married for 7 months, I was wondering if it works for my case or not.

Comment: I think in the eyes of the law you were not living 'together' for 3 years.

Comment: So you mean, I can qualify for a PR through him only if we have officially married for 3 years? @quantum

Comment: Strange, why your husband applies after 33 months of Blue Card and not 21, is he not speaking German? Why does he need to wait for one month now? it should be possible to apply in advance. For you the fastest way will be probably to get PR after 21 month with BlueCard

Comment: Yes he couldn't find time to complete the B1 certificate so he'll just apply after the 33 months now. Does this mean I cannot automatically get a PR as a spouse once my husband gets is? @AndreySapegin

Comment: There is definitely nothing automatic!